# I m trying to add google ad sense in a sample html but it shows error in the console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, adsense

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
This is the head of your page.
<title>Example HTML page</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
This is the body of your page.
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- horizontal ad -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-1677523677681098"
     data-ad-slot="1902657162"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
This is the body of your page.
</body>
</html>[enter image description here][1]
```

It shows ERR:FILE NOT FOUND.
I have used local adsgoogle.js but it didnt worked.
I haved attached the screenshot of the console below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/558XF.png

Comment: you attached the screenshot onto the code section. we cannot see the screenshot.

Comment: Can you add a fiddle or link to website?

Comment: http://chatrat.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: view-source:http://chatrat.000webhostapp.com/

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are seeing this is because of the line `//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js`. This is protocol-relative.

In your screenshot, you are loading from `file:///`—which doesn't exist on your computer at the path where it does on the `http` or `https` protocols.

To solve this, consider changing the `src` to `https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js` or pointing it to a relative path if you want the local `adsbygoogle.js` file to load.

Another solution, if you have Python installed locally, is to run a local webserver, and view your website via `http` instead of the `file` protocol. This can be done by opening a terminal, `cd`ing to your Desktop, and running `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`, and then visiting http://localhost:8000 in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ABP - Adb-blocker extension` in chrome. That is stopping ads from displaying. Try disabling `ABP Extension` and refresh (Ctrl+F5)